# Scrapy CrawlSpider is not following Links

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl a page that uses next buttons to move to new pages using scrapy. I'm using an instance of crawl spider and have defined the Linkextractor to extract new pages to follow. However, the spider just crawls the start url and stops at that. I've added the spider code and the log. Anyone has any idea why the spider is not able to crawl the pages.

```
        from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
        from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
        from realcommercial.items import RealcommercialItem
        from scrapy.selector import Selector
        from scrapy.http import Request

        class RealCommercial(CrawlSpider):
            name = "realcommercial"
            allowed_domains = ["realcommercial.com.au"]
            start_urls = [
                "http://www.realcommercial.com.au/for-sale/in-vic/list-1?nearbySuburb=false&autoSuggest=false&activeSort=list-date"
        ]
            rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor( allow = ['/for-sale/in-vic/list-\d+?activeSort=list-date']),

                           callback='parse_response',
                           process_links='process_links',
                           follow=True),
                     Rule(LinkExtractor( allow = []),

                           callback='parse_response',
                           process_links='process_links',
                           follow=True)]


            def parse_response(self, response):        
                sel = Selector(response)
                sites = sel.xpath("//a[@class='details']")
                #items = []
                for site in sites:
                    item = RealcommercialItem()
                    link = site.xpath('@href').extract()
                    #print link, '\n\n'
                    item['link'] = link
                    link = 'http://www.realcommercial.com.au/' + str(link[0])
                    #print 'link!!!!!!=', link
                    new_request = Request(link, callback=self.parse_file_page)
                    new_request.meta['item'] = item
                    yield new_request
                    #items.append(item)
                yield item
                return

            def process_links(self, links):
                print 'inside process links'
                for i, w in enumerate(links):
                    print w.url,'\n\n\n'
                    w.url = "http://www.realcommercial.com.au/" + w.url
                    print w.url,'\n\n\n'
                    links[i] = w

                return links

            def parse_file_page(self, response):
                #item passed from request
                #print 'parse_file_page!!!'
                item = response.meta['item']
                #selector
                sel = Selector(response)
                title = sel.xpath('//*[@id="listing_address"]').extract()
                #print title
                item['title'] = title

                return item
```

Log

```
                2015-11-29 15:42:55 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: realcommercial)
                2015-11-29 15:42:55 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, bot
                o
                2015-11-29 15:42:55 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 're
                alcommercial.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['realcommercial.
                spiders'], 'FEED_URI': 'aaa.csv', 'BOT_NAME': 'realcommercial'}
                2015-11-29 15:42:56 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter
                , TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
                2015-11-29 15:42:57 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddl
                eware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultH
                eadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMidd
                leware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
                2015-11-29 15:42:57 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddlewa
                re, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
                2015-11-29 15:42:57 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
                2015-11-29 15:42:57 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
                2015-11-29 15:42:57 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 i
                tems (at 0 items/min)
                2015-11-29 15:42:57 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
                2015-11-29 15:42:59 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.realcommercial
                .com.au/for-sale/in-vic/list-1?nearbySuburb=false&autoSuggest=false&activeSort=l
                ist-date> (referer: None)
                2015-11-29 15:42:59 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
                2015-11-29 15:42:59 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
                {'downloader/request_bytes': 303,
                 'downloader/request_count': 1,
                 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
                 'downloader/response_bytes': 30599,
                 'downloader/response_count': 1,
                 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
                 'finish_reason': 'finished',
                 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 29, 10, 12, 59, 418000),
                 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
                 'log_count/INFO': 7,
                 'response_received_count': 1,
                 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
                 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
                 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
                 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
                 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 29, 10, 12, 57, 780000)}
                2015-11-29 15:42:59 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself. There were two issues:

1. process_links was "http://www.realcommercial.com.au/" although it was already there. I thought it would give back the relative url.
2. The regular expression in link extractor was not correct.

I made changes to both of these and it worked.